# is it possible to write an array formula in google sheets that will increment cell referents?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

i am tracking traffic data and keeping a running tally of new members, as well as a running average.

what i am currently doing is manually adding the formula to each cell every day, for e. g.

| avg. daily attrition | avg. total attrition |
| --- | --- |
| `=AVERAGE(E2:E3)` | `=AVERAGE(H2:H3)` |
| `=AVERAGE(E2:E4)` | `=AVERAGE(H2:H4)` |
| `=AVERAGE(E2:E5)` | `=AVERAGE(H2:H5)` |
| `=AVERAGE(E2:E6)` | `=AVERAGE(H2:H6)` |
| (...) | (...) |
| `=AVERAGE(E2:E366)` | `=AVERAGE(H2:H366)` |

what i would like is a formula that only adds the new average to the latest cell, and doesn't affect the previous averages of older cells. so, using =AVERAGE(E2:E366) for the whole column is obviously right out.

i'm sure there's a way to do this, i just don't know what it is. i tried looking up array formulae, but based on how =ARRAY works, i don't think that would be suitable.

thanks in advance.

ETA: i found a tutorial. thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`=transpose(index(query(transpose(split(split(substitute(join("~",E2:E366),"~","#",sequence(rows(E2:E366))),"#"),"~")),"select avg(Col"&join("), avg(Col",sequence(rows(E2:E366)))&")"),2))`

With `transpose(split(split(substitute(join("~",E2:E366),"~","#",sequence(rows(E2:E366))),"#"),"~"))` we are creating a table like the one in C3:G8:

[image]

and with `"select avg(Col"&join("), avg(Col",sequence(rows(E2:E366)))&")"` (C9) we return the average of the values in the columns.

Comment: thank you for your answer! can i ask what sort of operation this is called, if i need to search for it again in future?

Comment: also, i would like to know both how this works and how to implement it, please?

Comment: This is called a running average. As for how it works, I updated my answer. What do you mean by "how to implement it"?

Comment: i pasted your code into a cell and got 'Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: TypeError: HY is undefined'. if this is a script i need to run, i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: To best get help please share your sheet or recreate the problem in a dummy one.

Comment: i found a tutorial for running averages. thank you for your help.